# How can I implement ng-class-odd in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I would like the odd table rows to bee colored. Angular has ng-class-odd and ng-class-even that works inside the scope of ng-repeat.

Can I somehow get the index of the repeat-for function in Aurelia?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is `$even` and `$odd` properties that is available on the items in an `repeat.for` binding.

You could conditionally apply a class like this -

```
<ul>
  <li repeat.for="item of items" class="${ $even ? 'my-class': '' }"></li>
</ul>
```